# Does having a light or laser pointer on my weapon give my position away to the enemy?

Tags: payday-2

Two of the weapon upgrades available in Payday 2 are the tactical light and the laser pointer which provides a gadget that can be turned on or off but that visually gives away your position.

Does having a light on my weapon or a laser pointer give my position away to the enemy or is the AI oblivious to a bright light pointing at them from the darkness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the light, but from what I have seen, guards don't notice the laser beams, despite them being very bright visually.

In my last "framing frame" I was watching through the cameras, and the guards regularly *should* have been able to see the beams of laser from our guys stealthing, but they did not alert.

Comment: From further practice of running around in the dark flashing lights at police, it looks like the flashlight has no effect on whether you can be seen or not also